# Persistent search from Sidebar - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, persistence, sidebar

I have a sidebar with a search function that looks for items. Once an item (course in this case) is clicked the show page appears to the right of the sidebar, However once it is clicked, the search list reverts to its initial (unsearched) state. How can I make persistent search aka how can I make the search remain what was searched. Here is my code:

Model

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.search(search)
        if search
          where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%")
        else
          all
        end
    end
end
```

View

```
<%= form_tag courses_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
private
def search_course
      @courses = Course.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4) #paginating
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your view, like this:

```
<%= form_tag courses_path, :method => 'get', :remote => true do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
<% end %>
```

That way the page won't refresh each time you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], value: params[:search] if params[:search] %>
```

This will set the value attribute of the input tag, generated by the text_field_tag rails helper, to `params[:search]`. `params[:search]` is the what the user types and submits and the value of the input tag will be set to `params[:search]` if `params[:search]` returns true.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.